# jdeps is failing with Concurrent Execution Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jdeps

I am trying to get dependencies for my spring boot jar using Jdeps. Following command i am running :-

```
jdeps --ignore-missing-deps --print-module-deps --multi-release=11 --recursive -cp BOOT-INF/lib/* x.jar
```

but the above command is failing with following error :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.tools.jdeps.MultiReleaseException
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.DependencyFinder.waitForTasksCompleted(DependencyFinder.java:271)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.DependencyFinder.parse(DependencyFinder.java:133)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.DepsAnalyzer.transitiveArchiveDeps(DepsAnalyzer.java:217)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.DepsAnalyzer.run(DepsAnalyzer.java:138)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.ModuleExportsAnalyzer.run(ModuleExportsAnalyzer.java:74)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask$ListModuleDeps.run(JdepsTask.java:1047)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:574)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:533)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.Main.main(Main.java:49)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.tools.jdeps.MultiReleaseException
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.DependencyFinder.waitForTasksCompleted(DependencyFinder.java:267)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: com.sun.tools.jdeps.MultiReleaseException
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.VersionHelper.add(VersionHelper.java:62)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.ClassFileReader$JarFileReader.readClassFile(ClassFileReader.java:360)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.ClassFileReader$JarFileIterator.hasNext(ClassFileReader.java:402)
        at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.DependencyFinder.lambda$parse$5(DependencyFinder.java:179)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832
```

Reason for the error :-

Above Jdeps command is working fine when i am running wut this POM.xml entries :-

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

But when I am adding Spring-boot Data JPA dependency, it is breaking :-

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I want dependecnies in comma seperated format.

Can someone please let me know the reason that why on adding Spring-Boot Data JPA, Jdeps is breaking.

I am using JDK 15 for this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the above is fixed in JDK 17 and jdeps is working fine with sprig data jpa dependency.